# HTML footer position - must body be parent element?

Tags: html, css, footer

Is it OK to put the footer element inside a div or must the body element be it's parent? I suspect the answer here is no but I just want to clarify

Comment: Depends on your layout... None of the HTML specs say that a footer must be a child of `<body>` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only restriction is an html-document having one root-node `html` and `html`containing `head`and `body`. For the position of the footer, you are free to use it nearly anywhere you like.

If you are unsure use the spec, it tells you, where a specific element may be positioned.

Comment: There are **many** limits on the structure of documents. Forms can't contain other forms. Interactive controls can't contain other interactive controls. Some elements may appear only in the head. Some elements can't have descendants. Lists can only have list item children. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I know that. Thats why i said "pretty" free. In this special example i was referring to footer <-> div.

Answer (score 2):

From [the spec for footer](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element):

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>     Where flow content is expected.

From [the spec for div](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element):

> Content model:
>     Flow content.

So, yes.

---

Also from the spec for footer:

> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element.

If it could only appear as a child of the body then that would probably read *The footer element represents a footer for the document*.